# Custom UserDefinedFunction in Hive

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hive, hiveql

**Problem Statement**

I created the below `UserDefinedFunction` to get the `yesterday's date` in the format I wanted as I will be passing the format into this below method from the query.

```
public final class YesterdayDate extends UDF {

         public String evaluate(final String format) { 
                 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format); 
                 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                 cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);     
                 return dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).toString(); 
                } 
}
```

So whenever I try to run the query like below by adding the jar to classpath and creating the temporary function `yesterdaydate`, I always get zero result back-

```
hive> create temporary function yesterdaydate as 'com.example.hive.udf.YesterdayDate';
OK
Time taken: 0.512 seconds
```

Below is the query I am running-

```
hive> SELECT * FROM REALTIME where dt= yesterdaydate('yyyyMMdd') LIMIT 10;
OK
```

And I always get zero result back but the data is there in that table for Aug 5th.

What wrong I am doing? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Query should be like this if today's date is Aug 6th- then the query will be like below by using the above user defined function-

```
SELECT * FROM REALTIME where dt= '20120805' LIMIT 10;
```

NOTE:- As I am working with `Hive 0.6` so it doesn’t support variable substitution thing, so I cannot use `hiveconf` here and the above table has been partitioned on `dt(date) column`.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-1*24*60*60,'%Y%m%d');

Comment: How is this using a UDF?